# Building elasticsearch from Source (Task :benchmarks:compileJava FAILED)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Trying build Elasticsearch from source.

Just installed OpenJAVA-11-sdk & jre.

below are `java` & `javac` & `echo $PATH` outputs as well.

```
rajesh@Rajesh-PC:~/elasticsearch$ ./gradlew  assemble
=======================================
Elasticsearch Build Hamster says Hello!
  Gradle Version        : 6.5
  OS Info               : Linux 4.15.0-111-generic (amd64)
  JDK Version           : 11 (JDK)
  JAVA_HOME             : /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
  Random Testing Seed   : 48BEB2A1EC142E2C
  In FIPS 140 mode      : false
=======================================

> Task :build-tools:jar
:build-tools:jar: A valid plugin descriptor was found for elasticsearch.enforce-deprecation-use-failures.properties but the implementation class org.elasticsearch.gradle.EnforceDeprecationFailuresPlugin was not found in the jar.

> Task :benchmarks:compileJava FAILED
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: java.base/java.lang.SuppressWarnings,java.base/java.lang.Override
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning

> Task :modules:lang-mustache:compileJava
Note: /home/rajesh/elasticsearch/modules/lang-mustache/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/script/mustache/MustacheScriptEngine.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':benchmarks:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
77 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 60 up-to-date

rajesh@Rajesh-PC:~/elasticsearch$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)

rajesh@Rajesh-PC:~/elasticsearch$ javac -version
javac 11.0.7

rajesh@Rajesh-PC:~/elasticsearch$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/home/rajesh/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Looking at the errors, it seems like there is a compilation error which is most probably because of the JDK version, as your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to JDK 11.**

Here are the ways by which you can resolve the issue :

1. If you have cloned the latest Elasticsearch source code from https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch, then to build Elasticsearch, JDK 14 is required. However, since Elasticsearch supports JDK 11, the build supports compiling with JDK 14 and testing on a JDK 11 runtime.
2. After installing JDK 14, and setting `JAVA_HOME` pointing to Java home of JDK 14 installation, run Elasticsearch source code with this command again `./gradlew :run`.
3. Once the process is fully started, then run curl in another window like this

`curl -u elastic:password localhost:9200`

To get a detailed explanation refer this [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-to-the-elasticsearch-codebase)

Comment: @hacker315 did u get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from u?

Comment: Hey @hacker315 are you able to resolve your issue by installing `JDK 14`, and pointing your `JAVA_HOME` to `JDK 14`

Comment: @hacker315 thank u for accepting and upvoting the answer :)